# PHP Json Encoding Syntax

Tags: php, json

I'm new to json and decided to use it because it looks promising. How does the syntax work?

Here is my simple php script:

```
$usernames = array('jake', 'john', 'jackie', 'jared');
$users = array();
for($i = 0; $i < 4; $i++)
{
    $users[$i]['id'] = $i;
    $users[$i]['name'] = $usernames[i];
}
$data = json_encode( $users );
echo $data;
```

It Outputs:

```
{"i":{"id":3,"name":null}}
```

I want it to output:

```
[{"id": 1,"name": "jake"},{"id": 2,"name": "john"},{"id": 3,"name": "jackie"},{"id": 4,"name": "jared"}]
```

Comment: You have a syntax error inside the `for` loop. `i` should be `$i`. See the working demo: https://eval.in/95092

Comment: **Pro tip**: [Enable error reporting during debugging](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6575502/)

Comment: avoid hard coding iteration quantity into your logic, and either get `count($usernames)` or use `foreach()`, if you change the length of your names list you may miss something. later on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just one line inside the loop will do it

```
$usernames = array('jake', 'john', 'jackie', 'jared');
$users = array();
for($i = 0; $i < 4; $i++)
{
    $users[] = array("id"=>$i+1,"name"=>$usernames[$i]);

}
$data = json_encode( $users );
echo $data;
```

Output as you wanted in your question

```
[{"id":1,"name":"jake"},{"id":2,"name":"john"},{"id":3,"name":"jackie"},{"id":4,"name":"jared"}]
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to use:

```
$usernames = array('jake', 'john', 'jackie', 'jared');
$users = array();
foreach($usernames as $id => $username)
{
    $users[$id]['id'] = $id + 1;
    $users[$id]['name'] = $username;
}
$data = json_encode( $users );
echo $data;
```

Comment: That would overwrite $users with every iteration, would need `$users[]` or `array_push()` and the structure would still be a bit incorrect.

Comment: I'd just simply have `$users[] = array('id'=>$id,'name'=>$username);` pretty much the same thing just not going to throw any chance of a notice of `$users[$id]` not existing as an array first

Comment: @Scuzzy, Yes, you right, but Abhik Chakraborty already do this

Answer (score 0):

```
$usernames = array('jake', 'john', 'jackie', 'jared');
$users = array();
for($i = 0; $i < 4; $i++)
{
    $user=array();
    $user['id'] = $i;
    $user['name'] = $usernames[$i];
    $users[]=$user;
}
$data = json_encode( $users );
echo $data;
```

Output:

```
[{"id":0,"name":"jake"},{"id":1,"name":"john"},{"id":2,"name":"jackie"},{"id":3,"name":"jared"}]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
$usernames = array('jake', 'john', 'jackie', 'jared');
$users = array();
for($i = 0; $i < 4; $i++)
{
    $users[$i]['id'] = $i;
    $users[$i]['name'] = $usernames[$i];
}
$data = json_encode( $users );
echo $data;
```

Changed,

```
$usernames[i]
```

To,

```
$usernames[$i]
```

And I think its better using a foreach loop instead of for..

Answer (score 0):

```
$usernames = array('jake', 'john', 'jackie', 'jared');

$users = array();

foreach($usernames as $id=>$username{
    $id++;
    $users[]=array('id'=>$id,'name'=>$username);
}

$data=json_encode($users);echo $data;
```

Comment: Please give some explanation, and just code.